# how to get the result from Illuminate\Support\Collection Object

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I'am using laravel framework with mongodb, the result of the query as follows

```
[JoinedDate] => Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
    (
        [0] => MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime Object
        (
        [milliseconds] => 1479118097917
        )
    )
)
```

How to read the result, to get milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your variable is called `$joinedDate`, you can try using:

```
$joinedDate->first()->milliseconds;
```